# Cannot open include file 'getopt.h'

Tags: c++

Firstly, I know nothing about C/C++, but I am trying to compile LCI https://github.com/justinmeza/lci under Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015, but I'm getting the following error:

Cannot open include file: 'getopt.h': No such file or directory.

I see that getopt is not part of Visual C so people are saying you have to implement your own. It looks like this is what I need:

https://github.com/skandhurkat/Getopt-for-Visual-Studio/blob/master/getopt.h

Problem is, I don't really know what to do with this file. I've been reading a fair bit and messing around for ages just to compile lci.exe!

Comment: `#include` the header in the file(s) that require it, not sure what else to say... what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: If you know nothing about C++ then trying to get other people's code to compile is surely the worst possible way to get started.  You won't learn anything about C++ and you'll have no idea how to solve trivial problems.  Write your own code first.  Exercises from an introductory book are best.

Comment: I completely agree :) But in this case, I'm interested purely in compiling the exe - I work in C# and don't have any real need to learn C/C++ at the moment.

Comment: I just took content of these files from 3rdparty folder and placed it directly in the place of include command. It worked. Somehow VS couldn't open these files even when they were there.

Answer (score 5):

Already emailed the OP about this, but here's the steps I followed in order to build lci successfully. The missing step seemed to be that Justin Meza neglected to mention that you need to install CMake as well in order for the install script to work. CMake will allow you to build C code against the glibc headers.

1. Install [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)
2. Install [Python 3.5.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/) (or latest Windows version)
3. Install Git for [Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) (if you haven't already)

   - Make sure to enable Git for the Windows command prompt
4. Install [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/)
5. Add MinGW and Python to your PATH environment variable. I'd double check that your paths to the executables are correct, mine looked like this:

   - C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin
   - C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32
6. Run a command prompt as administrator, and go to your Documents folder and clone the lci repository (if you haven't already):

   - git clone https://github.com/justinmeza/lci.git
7. Go into the lci directory, and run:

   - install.py --prefix="C:/Program Files/lci"
8. Add lci to you PATH, if using the default location add this to the end of your PATH:

   - C:\Program Files\lci\bin

I would have included some links to the various programs above in steps 1-4 but apparently I don't have enough reputation on StackOverflow for that...you should be able to find them easily enough in a quick Google search.

You should now be able to run lci from any command prompt. A good test would be to run the "HAI WORLD" code at lolcode.org.

Comment: On the home page of the [lci project](https://github.com/justinmeza/lci), at the top of the page, just under *LICENSE* and *ABOUT* section, in the *PREREQUISITES* section, the first one listed is... **CMake**...

Comment: I guess I stand corrected, but you'd think he'd locate that in a less obscure place under the build instructions.

Comment: No problem. But honestly I don't how see how the top of the page could be considered an *obscure* place. ;-)

Comment: It is if you're only used to looking at the build instructions for your specific platform. I'm accustomed to ALL of the relevant information for a successful build to be located in one place, in sequential order where you can't miss it. But hey, I'm just nitpicking really. Justin did a pretty good job on the whole with lci.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy getopt.h to the directory where .c files are, so the compiler can find it.

Comment: He doesn't have getopt.h under Microsoft Windows. Can't copy something that doesn't exist. He stated that he's using Windows 10, and getopt.h is part of glibc, of course.

Comment: He has shown a link to a port of getopt. Please read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the linked source code and it's contents, the project you're trying to build appears to be written for Linux. It might be possible to sufficiently rewrite it to be able to compile under Microsoft Windows, and Microsoft's compiler; or perhaps install something like MinGW.

However, given your stated lack of development experience, this does not appear to be something that you could easily handle on your own.

Comment: Definitely feels like I'm out of my depth - I'm far more at home in Windows/C# than I am in Linux/C!